# Падеж количественных числительных

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, числительные

Правильна ли падежная форма неопределенного количественного числительного в вопросительном предложении — "Сколько не хватает карандашей?"
Не должно ли быть "Скольких не хватает карандашей?" — если в ответ следует: "Не хватает пяти карандашей"?

Comment: НЕ с глаголами пишется раздельно! Я не верю, что человек оперирующий понятиями "падежная форма" и "неопределенное количественное числительное этого не знает". Что за атака жирных троллей?!

Comment: Вы меня напугали, здесь водятся тролли?! А как на форуме русского языка определить тонкого тролля? Я уже подозрительно оглядываюсь вокруг: иногда некоторые люди и их вопросы действительно кажутся странными. Наверное, не надо на них отвечать и с ними общаться? Могут эти тролли задавать вопросы, а ответами не интересоваться? В любом случае, есть, наверное, способы борьбы с ними. Например, насмешка, ирония. То есть надо вычислить тролля и дать ему понять, что он разоблачен. И применить ответный троллинг.

Comment: @Sharon А как им не водится-то, если ві их регулярно прикармливаете?

Comment: И я тоже прикармливаю? Но Вы ведь, наверное, не скажете, кто они. Ладно, я сама догадаюсь.

Comment: Повтор вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы, **если это числительное.**

У Ожегова читаем:

> СКОЛЬКО.1. мест. нареч. и союзн. сл. Как много, каково количество. С.
>   стоит? С. времени? Ешь, с. хочешь. 2. (скольких, сколькими, по
>   скольку), числит. неопр.-колич. Обозначает общее указание на
>   количество. Во скольких городах побывал! В скольких томах это
>   сочинение? По скольку дней отдыхали? 3. нареч. В какой мере,
>   насколько. С. помню, он всегда был такой.

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE

В вопросительных предложениях мы **можем употреблять и неопределенно-количественные числительные, и вопросительные наречия в значении "как много? каково количество?"** Видимо, автор приведённого Вами примера как раз употребил наречие. Это вполне корректно.

НЕОПРЕДЕЛЕННО-КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННЫЕ СЛОВА И ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫЕ - не совсем простая тема.
Под термином «неопределенно-количественные слова» принято понимать слова мало (немало), много (немного), сколько (несколько).
Отнесение их к той или иной части речи вызывает споры:

В. В. Виноградов - «неопределенно-колич. имена числительные»,

А. Н. Гвоздев — «неопределенные числительные».

В АГ 1953 г. они отнесены к числительным.

Другое мнение: слова мало (немало), много (немного) являются наречиями, а слова сколько (несколько), столько — местоимениями.

Нет разряда числительных, которые имели бы такую неограниченную соче­таемость.
Слова мало (немало), много (немного) сочетаются со всеми разрядами существи­тельных. Ср.: мало (много) тетрадей.
Они не способны выражать точное количество предметов,не имеют счетно-числового значения,в них ярко выражены признаки наречий:

1) способность определять глагол (мало занимаешься);

2) наличие форм сравнительной степени (ср.: много читай — больше читай)

3) наличие форм субъективной оценки (мало времени — маловато времени);

4) способность сочетаться с наречиями степени (очень мало);

5) отсутствие падежных форм.

Сколько (несколько), столько не относятся к числительным. Они обладают местоименными (обобщенно-указательными) значениями.
Порядковые слова первый, второй хотя имеют отношение к числу, но явл прил. Не относятся к числу и неопределенно-количественные слова.
http://uchebana5.ru/cont/2733637-p8.html

Answer (score 1):

Во втором ответе я добавлю информацию о Р.п.

2. **ХВАТАТЬ**,  2. **кого-чего.** Разг. Иметься в большом количестве. Сегодня дел у меня хватает. Забот хватает. ◊ Не хватает кого-чего. О чём-л. неожиданном и неприятном; о том, кто мешает или не нужен. Тебя тут только не хватает. Этого ещё не хватало! Возглас, выражающий неодобрение, негодование по какому-л. поводу.

Как мы видим, даже в разговорном варианте **следует использовать Р.п.: не хватает (чего?).** Но надо посмотреть, как это правило соблюдается **для числового оборота.**

Рассмотрим фразы: *Сколько не хватает карандашей? Сколько карандашей не хватает?*

Они выглядят вполне **приемлемо**, так как мы читаем: ***не хватает карандашей.***  Всё правильно, родительный падеж. На слух не определяется, что ***не хватает*** управляет числовым оборотом, а не формой ***карандашей***.

Поэтому в устной речи такие фразы  допустимы, корректное управление характерно для письменной речи.

Письменная речь:  ***Скольких*** карандашей не хватает? Не хватает **пяти** карандашей.

Устная речь: ***Сколько*** карандашей не хватает? Не хватает **пяти** карандашей.

Answer (score 0):

**Сколько карандашей**  лежит в коробке (И.п.)? — В коробке **семь карандашей** (И.п.)

**Скольких карандашей**  не хватает (Р.п.) ? — Не хватает **пяти карандашей** (Р.п.).

Все предельно просто. ***Сколько*** — **неопределенно-количественное числительное** и ведет себя так же, как и обычное количественное числительное.

**А как?**

Числительные в сочетании с существительными образуют **счетный оборот.** В И.п. и В.п. числительное задает существительному Р.п., а в остальных падежах, в том числе в Р.п., согласуется с существительным.

*Сколько карандашей — **скольких карандашей** (Р.п.) — скольким карандашам —сколькими карандашами — о скольких карандашах.*

**Примечание**

Называть неопределенно-количественные числительные можно
по-разному, но важно то, что **от названия их грамматические свойства не зависят.**

В Грамматике-80  приведена **такая классификация**. Количественные числительные разделяются на (1) определенно-количественные и (2) неопределенно-количественные.

Неопределенно-количественные числительные или обозначают **неопределенное число** (*мало, много*), или **указывают на него** (местоименные числительные *несколько, сколько*).