# Когда слово "сколько" является наречием, а не числительным?

Tags: числительные

Этот вопрос связан с темой, которую уже обсуждали

[Падеж количественных числительных](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453679/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

- Правильна ли падежная форма неопределенно-количественного числительного в вопросительном предложении  *Сколько не хватает карандашей*?
- В вопросительных предложениях мы можем употреблять и неопределенно-количественные числительные, и вопросительные наречия в значении "как много? каково количество?" Видимо, автор приведённого Вами примера как раз употребил наречие. Это вполне корректно.

Полагаю, что  этот ответ неверен.  Мы не можем  считать *сколько* наречием или числительным по своему усмотрению – как кому нравится. **В этом примере *сколько* является только  числительным, но не наречием.**

Это мое мнение, но так ли это?

**Пояснение**

1) Можно ли ***сколько*** назвать местоименным наречием? Как говорится, можно, но осторожно. **Каждый грамматический класс слов** определяется по семантике, морфологии и синтаксису.

2) Вот и давайте анкетируем это «наречие». Какое **значение** у слова *сколько*? Правильно, количественное. **По падежам** изменяется? Очень даже, все шесть падежей  имеются. Кажется, оно **сочетается** с существительными, образуя счетный оборот. Да, конечно, как и самое «правильное» количественное числительное, **по основному правилу:** задает Р.п. существительному в начальной форме и согласуется с ним в косвенных падежах.

3) Тогда какое же это наречие? **Наречие** – это неизменяемая форма слова (кроме сравн. степени).   Наречие обозначает признак действия или признак признака, сочетается с глаголами, прилагательными и другими наречиями, во всех сочетаниях используется связь примыкание .

4) Поэтому по всем рассмотренным признакам  ***сколько*** — это местоименное числительное. И в составе числительных оно образует особую группу неопределенно-количественных числительных.

5) Но иногда  местоименному числительному удается **перейти в наречие.** Например:  Сколько стоит? Сколько времени? (В этом случае семантика глагола уже как-то связана с количественным значением).

Но тогда  *сколько* **меняется:** оно использует только одну начальную форму, сочетается с глаголами и уж, конечно, **ни в коем случае не образует с существительными счетного оборота.** Такое четкое деление на наречия и числительные мы видим **у Ожегова**.

https://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=28953

А вот **у  Кузнецова**  мы видим уже другое:

СКОЛЬКО. I. **местоим. нареч. (нар.-разг.)** скольких, скольким, по скольку и (разг.) по сколько; мн. скольких; 1. Какое количество? как много? С. тебе лет? **В скольких томах роман?**

Цирк, да и только. **Не числительное, не наречие, а народно-разговорное наречие.**  Это, наверное, то, которое по падежам изменяется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не вижу причин называть здесь **числительное** наречием экзотической формы. *Наречие* было бы в вопросе, на который ожидается качественный ответ, а не количественный.

> -- *Насколько* тебе не хватает карандашей? - *Настолько*, что кушать не
>   могу.

А в нашем примере (сколько не хватает) - сочетание обычного числительного в *винительном* падеже с управляемым им существительным в *родительном*. Вариация с родительным падежом числительного (*скольк**их*** - напр. из общего числа не хватает) возможна здесь в силу присутствия отрицания и принципиальной возможности контекстных порогов хватки/нехватки (скольк**их** хватило бы или не хватает из имевшихся). Чтобы это увидеть, можно изменить пример в позитивном направлении с более простым по смыслу глаголом, когда родительный падеж числительного не возникает как альтернатива (сколько = **какое количество**):

> -- **Сколько** карандашей тебе *нужно* (иметь) для счастья? -- **Сто** штук!

Comment: Спасибо, Александр за ответ, но я не поняла главного: 1)  В заданном предложении "сколько" является местоименным числительным в составе числового оборота.Это ни в коем случае не наречие.  Это утверждение правильное? 2) А в каком предложении "сколько" является наречием? У вас есть такой пример?

Comment: Да, я считаю, что в исх. примере м. числительное, а чтобы "сколько" оказалось наречием (в отл. от "насколько") не могу придумать пример ("сколько времени" подразумевает количество времени).

Comment: Ожегов уже придумал: Сколько сейчас времени? Сколько это стоит? Наверное, это тоже наречия:  Сколько можно тебе повторять!  Сколько тебя еще ждать?

Comment: Можно и как сокращения это рассматривать - от сочетаний "сколько же (денег)", "сколько (раз) можно", "сколько (времени) ждать". Скорее, в каких-нибудь идиоматических выражениях (когда нечем измерить - нет стандартной меры) бывает: сколько же (= до чего же много) его тут было - всю комнатушку собой занимал!